# Number of words with k max number of consecutive vowels

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, recurrence-relations

Given a word length $n$ and max number of consecutive vowels $k$ ,we need to tell how many words that we can
form using given constraints.

$n=3$ and $k=2$ means we have to tell the number of words of length $3$ and in which we can use at most $k$ consecutive vowels.

I know its a dynamic programming problem but unable to figure out the recurrence. Please help!

The word should be formed using only letters using $21$ consonants and $5$ vowels.

Comment: are there 5 vowels and 26 characters in total?

Comment: Yes 21 consonants and 5 vowels

Comment: also, total number of vowels can be any as long as they are not consecutive?

Comment: yes restrictions is only on consecutive vowels

Comment: It seems to me like a recurrence equation for $n$ is $$T(n+1, k) = 26 T(n, k) - 5 (5^k)(21) T(n-k-1, k)$$ for $n>k$, since by adding 1 letter to the end, you can form 26 times more words, except that you have to subtract the words that end in $k$ vowels if the letter you add is a vowel. However, I haven’t thought of a recurrence equation in $k$.

Comment: Oh, I think you can use $T(n,k\ge n)=26^n$ and $T(n,n-1)= 26^n-5^n$ as your base cases, then the recurrence equation above should be all you need.

Comment: why you multiplied 5 and 21 in T(n-k-1,k) ?

Comment: Subtracting the illegal words formed if the new letter was a vowel (5), preceded by $k$ vowels $(5^k)$, preceded by a consonant (21), preceded by a legal word of length $n-k-1$.

Comment: Actually, to use the recurrence equation above when $n=k+1$, you would need to use $$T(n+1,k) = 26T(n,k) -5(5^k)(21)$$

Comment: thanks I got it  But i also want to tell you my thinking because i m not sure whether earlier i was thinking correct or not   like can we do something like this T(i,j) = word of length i
with j consecutive vowel where i <=n && j<=k and then finally we can say our answer is
summation of T[n,1....k]

Comment: Not the equations I wrote. $T(n,k)$ is the number of words of length $n$ with no more than $k$ consecutive vowels. You wouldn’t use a summation. You would solve the recurrence equation for an analytic solution.